# Как активировать масштабирование колесиком мыши, без нажатия на Ctrl?

Tags: inkscape

> Нашел в сети:
> CTRL+крутить колёсико мыши: масштабирует в позиции курсора. (Если в
> меню Файл ⇨ Настроить Inkscape ⇨ Прокрутка поставить галочку в
> чекбоксе По умолчанию колесо мыши масштабирует вид, то колёсико начнет
> масштабировать без нажатия CTRL.

B Inkscape 1.1, такая инструкция не работает. Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 2):

Правка - параметры - интерфейс - сочетания клавиш - modifiers (вкладка) - холст - масштаб холста.

Это настройка поведения мыши в сочетании с клавишами-модификаторами. Снимаете модификатор ctrl с масштаба холста и устанавливаете его на vertical pan. Таким образом вертикальная прокрутка теперь будет работать с контролом, а масштабирование будет осуществляться простой прокруткой.
На мой взгляд вполне логичный способ настройки, хоть и непривычный на первый взгляд.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]